# Yii2 Oracle PDO

Tags: php, pdo, oracle11g, yii2

I have the following in my php.ini file

`extension=php_oci8_11g.dll`

`extension=php_pdo_oci.dll`

When I run `phpinfo()` I get the following back:

[image]

Does PDO_OCI being blank mean i'm missing something - if so what?

Whilst going through Yii docs (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html) it says

`Connection represents a connection to a database via PDO.`

My queries have worked fine until, I've tried to use `bindParam()`. In which now I get `Class 'app\models\PDO' not found` as an error?

I have just ran `if(class_exists("PDO"))` and it returned true.

Comment: `PDO_OCI` is not blank. It says you have the driver for oracle version 8 or better and it is enabled. In the `PDO` entry it says that `oci` is available.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for confirming. So I should be able to run a PDO query without any problems?

Comment: If you use PDO constants in a namespaced code then you need to use `\PDO` e.g. `\PDO::OCI_INT`. As PDO is in the global namespace. By default PHP prefixes unqualified class names with the current namespace. Hence the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time on gitter and looking into it. It does seem that I need to namespace PDO to run these queries as Ryan mentioned

So declare in the model.

`use PDO;`